# Rails 1. order by with one-to-many relation. 2. order by computed value with different columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table named "items", and "orders".

item has many orders, order belongs to an item.

When doing query over items

1. how to order the result by the number of orders one item has?
2. how to order by created_at+duration-current_time? (created_at and duration are columns in items table, duration is integer indicating number of days within which the item is active, current time is the time when the query happens. What I am trying to get from this query is items ordered by their distances to expiration.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you need an understanding of GROUP statements and COUNT. As well as joins. You will need all 3 for this.
2) you don't, you just do order("created_at DESC")

Comment: Don't ever put current time into an Order clause, it's a constant so redundant. I think you might be going about your problem the wrong way. Duration is what? Number of days since created at?! If so it's redundant and you can just use "created_at ASC" which is oldest first or "created_at DESC" which is most recent first.

Comment: Duration is the time period within which the item is active. What I am trying to do is to sort the items by time period it is going to expire.

Comment: Ah, you're far better treating those as date fields then. I would set up a start_on and end_on - that also gives you the benefit of no having to put an item live the instance it is created. Items can be scheduled to go live etc. you can the. Do your sort by end_on ASC.